# Flexbox does not work in Safari, striked out in Web inspector

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, safari-web-inspector

I'm using `display: flexbox` for a div container cointaining a number of squares (to make them align nicely horizontally), and it works fine in Chrome, but not in Safari 8.0, where it's striked out like this:

[image]

```
#grid {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 415px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
    width: 166px;
    height: 185px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 166px 125px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background: #FFF;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: May be your styles are overwritten by some other styles?.

Comment: I tried adding !important to them, no luck. The only other one below is the User Agent Style sheet.

Comment: Safari does support [flex](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) I don't feel right until i see your site.

Comment: It's http://instadj.com – the video thumbnails grid.

Comment: Use prefix `display:-webkit-flex;` guess that works

Comment: Ah, thanks, just had to add browser prefixes to everything flexbox related.

Comment: Sorry, thought you meant I should post it myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use prefix so does safari supports

```
#grid {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 415px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: A year and a half later and modern Safari is supposed to be working without prefixes, but there are still some issues. Here's a newer answer with updated info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137085/flexbox-code-working-on-all-browsers-except-safari-why/35137869