# Flexbox code working on all browsers except Safari. Why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Grid columns with list tags, I need to display in correct order per every 3 columns, with auto width enabled for every extra HTML list elements.

This is my example:

```css
 <style>
        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 150px;
            width:auto;
        }
    
        li {
            float: left;
            display: inline-block;
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    </ul>
```

This is what I have tried so far and works absolutely fine on every other browser but not compatible with Safari browser unless I add this: `display: -webkit-flex;`.

I want to convert the output like this:

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8 11
3 6 9 12
```

It's important I get this working for Safari browser so far I cant seem to solve this problem at all, I would appropriate any help :)

Test link:

http://jsfiddle.net/rafcastro77/3zd7yspg/59/

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Flexbox is a CSS3 technology. This means it's relatively new and some browsers don't provide full support for flex properties.

*Here's a run-down:*

- IE 8 and 9 *do not* support flexbox. If you're wanting to use flex properties in these browsers, don't bother wasting your time. A  [flexbox polyfill](https://github.com/doctyper/reflexie) made the rounds for a while, but it didn't work well and is no longer maintained.
- IE 10 supports a [previous version of flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/) and requires [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). Be aware that certain properties from the current spec aren't supported in IE10 (such as `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`). See the [Flexbox 2012 Property Index](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/#property).
- IE 11 is good, but buggy. It's based on the [current flexbox standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/). See the *KNOWN ISSUES* tab on [this page](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for some of the problems. Also see: [flex property not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276)
- With Chrome, Firefox and Edge you're good all around. You'll find minor bugs and inconsistencies but there are usually easy fixes. You'll need to be aware of [Implied Minimum Flex Sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276), which sometimes causes sizing and scrollbar problems.
- Safari versions 9 and up support the current flexbox spec without prefixes. Older Safari versions, however, require `-webkit-` prefixes. Sometimes `min-width` and `max-width` cause alignment problems which can be resolved with `flex` equivalents. See  [Flex items not stacking properly in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36636243/3597276)

For a complete review of flexbox browser support, see this page:
http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

For a quick way to add many (but not necessarily all) vendor prefixes use [**Autoprefixer**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). For Safari, see [**this article**](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html) for `-webkit-` prefixes that some prefix generators don't include.

For a list of common flex bugs and their workarounds see [**Flexbugs**](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs).

Also, on this site, there's:

- [**Flexbox Tag Info**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flexbox/info)

Answer (score 26):

It works for me **display: -webkit-inline-box;** in safari.

Comment: it does work; but what about other flex utilities in safari ?

Comment: I used this in conjunction with the Safari (7.1+) specific targeting code so as to avoid conflict with other browsers, Thank you so much Saravana ! 
https://www.ryadel.com/en/css3-media-query-target-only-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/

Answer (score -4):

you could use bootstrap, and changed in your code in next lines with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            /*
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            */
            height: 150px;
            width:auto;
        }
    
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="d-flex flex-column flex-wrap align-content-start">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions with library unless the OP uses them or asks for the solution to use it.